# Flask-RESTful render_template cannot work

Tags: flask, flask-restful

I am new to flask，and I try to use Flask-RESTful to make flask work in restful way. However, I cannot render the HTML, while I try to return `render_template` it returns the source code of the HTML，
it is in this way [Flask render template not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19315567/flask-render-template-not-working)

I try the answer and it works，however I cannot input parameters like

```
render_template('index.html',titile="title","passwd"="123456")
```

It shows me  `SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression`. Can any one help me solve this problem?

Comment: find me so stupid。。。

Answer (score 3):

You have quotation marks wrapped around your `passwd`, which is invalid syntax when using `kwargs`.

Just remove the `"`

```
render_template('index.html', titile="title", passwd="123456")
```

Comment: haha, its my fault, I make a small mistake. You and Brian KH give me the right answer, thanks!

Comment: @poople I am glad I was able to help! If the answer has provided you a solution to your problem, feel free to accept the answer

Answer (score 3):

Flask-RESTful does not use render_template. It is designed to work with REST API calls and render JSON responses. Unless you are building a REST API, you don't need Flask-RESTful, just Flask.

To address your specific render_template() issue, I agree with Wondercricket.

Comment: I think you are right. At the beginning, I just use Flask-RESTful to make flask work in RESTFUL way, however, I cannot find the render method, but I try this way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19315567/flask-render-template-not-working. It works, thanks!